# How do I dual boot my laptop using a new internal Disk?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

So I've been using my laptop for over a year and I've heard a lot of people around me tell me that switching to Ubuntu/Linux based systems is extremely helpful/useful and that I'd learn a lot.

I currently have 512GB SSD in my laptop. I've heard that dual booting a laptop would mean that I'd have to backup all my data and partition my disk after which I'd have to reinstall everything. So I've decided to buy an additional internal disk and dedicate it for Ubuntu entirely (I genuinely don't have any idea how this works and am assuming that I can do that.). This way I don't have to get rid of any of my existing data or back it up.

Is it possible to do this? How do I go about it? I'm still very new to all of this and am worried if I make an incorrect move I can mess up my entire system and lose all my data.

Comment: Please let me know how I can explain my situation better or format this question better or anything on those lines. This is my first question here and I'm more than interested to learn to ask better questions and improve

Comment: There is no kown method to replace backups. Wether you install an additional OS or not. If your data are of any value to you, back them up!

Comment: Does laptop support two drives? Most do not. And many that install a drive to the DVD slot (which newer systems do not even have), are not bootable. There are some work arounds. An alternative is an external SSD, if you have USB3 ports it will be almost as fast as an internal drive. I upgraded my M.2 SSD to larger NVMe drive and put M.2 SSD into external USB to M.2 adapter and it has worked better than I expected.

Comment: Computer hard drives fail from time to time wether they be SSD  or spinning rust. If you have anything of value to you on your disk it is essential to have backups. It might not feel essential now but you will greatly regret not having backups if you loose irreplaceable photos for example. What you have heard is not quite right. You backup your windows system and data so you can easily recover if things go wrong when you install Ubuntu. You don’t need to reinstall windows, you just install Ubuntu. The Ubuntu installer will do the job for you and only rarely goes wrong if you follow a guide